# K-Means Clustering - F# Learning Challenge

Tags: f#, clustering

Inspired by [this blog](http://clear-lines.com/blog/post/K-Means-Clustering-in-FSharp.aspx) I went on implementing my own version as a F# learning challenge. It turned out to be quite different than the original (but somewhat faster for large samples).

The first code part below defines some test types and function delegates:

```
namespace FSLib
open System

// Test Type: Indexed Point in plane
type Point2D(x: float, y: float, i: int) =
  member this.X = x
  member this.Y = y
  member this.Index = i
  override this.ToString() = String.Format("{0}: [{1:F6}; {2:F6}]", this.Index, this.X, this.Y)

// Test Type: Indexed Point in space
type Point3D(x: float, y: float, z: float, i: int) =
  member this.X = x
  member this.Y = y
  member this.Z = z
  member this.Index = i
  override this.ToString() = String.Format("{0}: [{1:F6}; {2:F6}; {3:F6}]", this.Index, this.X, this.Y, this.Z)

// Function Prototype/delegate for 'a: a1 < a2 => 1 else a1 > a2 => -1 else a1 = a2 => 0
type Comparer<'a> = 'a -> 'a -> int
// Function Prototype/delegate for a function that calculates the 'distance' of some kind between two instances of 'a
type DistanceFunc<'a> = 'a -> 'a -> float
// Function Prototype/delegate for a function calculating a new centroid from a sequence of 'a's - returns a tuple (index, 'a)
type CentroidCalculator<'a> = int -> 'a seq -> int * 'a
```

Then a generic type/class that runs the optimization on the provided data:

```
// Type/class definition/implementation of KMeanCluster
type KMeanCluster<'a when 'a : equality>(comparer : Comparer<'a>, distanceFunc : DistanceFunc<'a>, centroidCalculator : CentroidCalculator<'a>) = 
  let compare = comparer
  let distance = distanceFunc
  let calculateCentroid = centroidCalculator

  // Returns the nearest centroid in argument centroids according to argument point
  let nearestCluster point centroids = 
    centroids |> Seq.sortBy(fun p -> distance point p) |> Seq.head

  // Returns a new list of cluster centroids by grouping the argument samples around the argument (old) centroids
  let calculateCentroids samples centroids =
    samples 
    |> Seq.groupBy(fun s -> nearestCluster s centroids)
    |> Seq.mapi(fun i g -> calculateCentroid i (snd g))
    |> Seq.sortBy(fun c -> fst c)
    |> Seq.map(fun c -> snd c)
    |> Seq.toList

  // Checks if two lists of same type is pairwise equal: if not => true else false
  let hasChanged list1 list2 =
    match List.compareWith compare list1 list2 with
    | 0 -> false
    | _ -> true

  // Runs the input data and returns the optimized cluster centroids
  member this.Calculate seedCentroids samples = 
    let mutable clusterCentroids = seedCentroids |> List.map(fun p -> p)
    let mutable newCentroids = calculateCentroids samples clusterCentroids

    // This is an iterative process continueing until completed optimization 
    // ctor argument 'comparer' could have some kind of tolerance build in as it is responsible for
    // ending the process
    while hasChanged clusterCentroids newCentroids do
      clusterCentroids <- newCentroids
      newCentroids <- calculateCentroids samples clusterCentroids

    newCentroids
```

Finally the client code and a sample generator function:

```
open System
open FSLib

let createData count = 
  let rand = Random(5)
  let min = -500
  let max = 500
  [ for i in 1 .. count -> [| (float)(rand.Next(min, max)); (float)(rand.Next(min, max)); (float)(rand.Next(min, max)) |]]

// Test Case for FSLib.Point2D:
let kmc1_2D data initailCentroids = 
  // Converts the initialCentroids list of float[3] to list of Point2D
  let seedCentroids = initailCentroids |> List.mapi(fun i (c : float[]) -> Point2D(c.[0], c.[1], i))
  // Converts the data a sequence of Point2D objects
  let samples = data |> Seq.mapi(fun i (d : float[]) -> Point2D(d.[0], d.[1], i))

  seedCentroids |> Seq.iter(fun x -> printfn "%A" x)
  printfn "\n"

  // Compares two points: as our only concern is whether they are equal or not it returns either 1 (unequal) or 0 (equal)
  let compare (point1 : Point2D) (point2 : Point2D) = if point1.X <> point2.X || point1.Y <> point2.Y then 1 else 0

  // Calculates and returns the geometric squared distance between two points
  let squaredDistance(point1 : Point2D) (point2 : Point2D) : float =
    let dx = point1.X - point2.X
    let dy = point1.Y - point2.Y
    dx * dx + dy * dy

  // Calculates and returns a tuple of argument index and the geometric average (centroid) of the argument points (index, centroid)
  let calculateCentroid index points =
    let mutable x = 0.0
    let mutable y = 0.0
    points |> Seq.iter(fun (p : Point2D) -> 
                         x <- x + p.X
                         y <- y + p.Y)
    let length = (float)(Seq.length points)
    (index, Point2D(x / length, y / length, index))

  // Instantiate an instance of KMeanCluster, calculates and prints the result
  let kmean = KMeanCluster<Point2D>(compare, squaredDistance, calculateCentroid)  
  let result = kmean.Calculate seedCentroids samples
  result |> List.iter(fun x -> printfn "%A" x)

  printfn "\nEND 2D"
  ignore

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
  let centroids = [ [| 0.; 0.; 0. |]; [| 20.; 30.; 40. |]; [| -40.; -50.; -60. |] ]
  let data = createData 1000

  kmc1_2D data centroids ignore 

  printfn "\nEND PROGRAM"
  let k = Console.ReadLine()
  0
```

I would like any comment on the F# language/functional programming specifics ideom, workflow etc. (don't waste time on error handling and the mathematics). As a OO-programmer I find it rather F#-ish, but as a F# specialist you may have another opinion?

Comment: Why are your points classes instead of records?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin: For no reason at all. You are right, in the real world they should be records/structs.

Comment: I wrote an answer, but I'm a bit confused with `Index` in the `Point2D`, `Point3D`. Are you sure it is necessary? In my opinion, is a bit of "white crow".

Comment: @FoggyFinder: You are right about the Index; It is a leftover from an earlier approach where it was needed. I was trying to keep track of the centroid order in some way, but that is unnecessay in here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.
F# there's such an amazing opportunity as partial application. So you don`t need write:

```
result |> List.iter(fun x -> printfn "%A" x)
```

just:

```
result |> List.iter printfn "%A"
```

Read more [here about it](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/partial-application/)

2.
In function `hasChanged` no need to use `match`, since only two possible Boolean variant:

```
  let hasChanged list1 list2 =
    Seq.compareWith compare list1 list2 <> 0
```

3.
F# have a strong functional component, it is better to do without the use of mutable variables (in function `calculateCentroid` and `Calculate`).

```
    static member calculateCentroid index points =
        let lng = points |> Seq.length |>  float
        points
        |> Seq.fold
            (fun acc v -> {acc with X = acc.X + v.X; Y = acc.Y + v.Y})
            {X = 0.0; Y = 0.0; Index = index} 
        |> fun v -> v.Index, {v with X = v.X / lng; Y = v.Y / lng}
```

4.
You can use methods such as List.init and Array.init, it is more convenient to generate the initial data:

```
let createData count z = 
  let rand = Random(5)
  let min = -500
  let max = 500
  List.init count 
    (fun _ -> Array.init z (fun _ -> rand.Next(min, max) |> float))
```

5.
Method `kmc1_2D` has a lot of features that are logically associated with a Point2D. Also, a side effect in the form of console output. Functions better to make a separate module or make them members of a type.

**Edit** Removed `Index`.

So as `calculateCentroid` is average, then if you add a few operators:

```
static member (+) (point1 : Point2D, point2 : Point2D) =  
    {X = point1.X + point2.X; Y = point1.Y + point2.Y}

static member Zero = {X = 0.0; Y = 0.0}
static member DivideByInt (point: Point2D, number: int)  = 
    let fnum = float number
    {X = point.X / fnum; Y = point.Y / fnum}
```

you can write:

```
static member calculateCentroid (points: seq<Point2D>) =
    points
    |> Seq.average
```

Given this, your code can be modified as follows:

Module Point2D:

```
module Point2D
open System

type Point2D = 
    {X:float; Y:float}
    with 
    override this.ToString() = 
            String.Format("[{0:F6}; {1:F6}]", this.X, this.Y)

    static member (+) (point1 : Point2D, point2 : Point2D) =  
        {X = point1.X + point2.X; Y = point1.Y + point2.Y}

    static member Zero = {X = 0.0; Y = 0.0}
    static member DivideByInt (point: Point2D, number: int)  = 
        let fnum = float number
        {X = point.X / fnum; Y = point.Y / fnum}

    static member compare (point1 : Point2D) (point2 : Point2D) = 
            if point1.X <> point2.X || point1.Y <> point2.Y 
            then 1 else 0

  // Calculates and returns the geometric squared distance between two points
    static member squaredDistance (point1 : Point2D) (point2 : Point2D) : float =
        let dx = point1.X - point2.X
        let dy = point1.Y - point2.Y
        dx * dx + dy * dy

  // Calculates and returns a tuple of argument index and the geometric average (centroid) of the argument points (index, centroid)
    static member calculateCentroid (points: seq<Point2D>) =
        points
        |> Seq.average
```

Module Point3D:

```
module Point3D
open System

type Point3D = 
    {X:float; Y:float; Z:float}
    with 
    override this.ToString() = 
            String.Format("[{0:F6}; {1:F6}; {2:F6}]", 
                this.X, this.Y, this.Z)

    static member (+) (point1 : Point3D, point2 : Point3D) =  
        {X = point1.X + point2.X; Y = point1.Y + point2.Y ; Z = point1.Z + point2.Z}

    static member Zero = {X = 0.0; Y = 0.0; Z = 0.0}
    static member DivideByInt (point: Point3D, number: int)  = 
        let fnum = float number
        {X = point.X / fnum; Y = point.Y / fnum ; Z = point.Z / fnum}

    static member compare (point1 : Point3D) (point2 : Point3D) = 
        if point1.X <> point2.X || point1.Y <> point2.Y || point1.Z <> point2.Z 
        then 1 else 0

  // Calculates and returns the geometric squared distance between two points
    static member squaredDistance (point1 : Point3D) (point2 : Point3D) : float =
        let dx = point1.X - point2.X
        let dy = point1.Y - point2.Y
        let dz = point1.Z - point2.Z
        dx * dx + dy * dy + dz * dz

  // Calculates and returns a tuple of argument index and the geometric average (centroid) of the argument points (index, centroid)
    static member calculateCentroid (points: seq<Point3D>) =
        points
        |> Seq.average
```

Module FSLib

```
module FSLib

// Function Prototype/delegate for 'a: a1 < a2 => 1 else a1 > a2 => -1 else a1 = a2 => 0
type Comparer<'a> = 'a -> 'a -> int
// Function Prototype/delegate for a function that calculates the 'distance' of some kind between two instances of 'a
type DistanceFunc<'a> = 'a -> 'a -> float
// Function Prototype/delegate for a function calculating a new centroid from a sequence of 'a's - returns a tuple (index, 'a)
type CentroidCalculator<'a> = 'a seq -> 'a

// Type/class definition/implementation of KMeanCluster
type KMeanCluster<'a when 'a : equality>(comparer : Comparer<'a>, distanceFunc : DistanceFunc<'a>, centroidCalculator : CentroidCalculator<'a>) = 
  let compare = comparer
  let distance = distanceFunc
  let calculateCentroid = centroidCalculator

  // Returns the nearest centroid in argument centroids according to argument point
  let nearestCluster point centroids = 
    centroids 
    |> Seq.sortBy (distance point)
    |> Seq.head

  // Returns a new list of cluster centroids by grouping the argument samples around the argument (old) centroids
  let calculateCentroids samples centroids =
    samples 
    |> Seq.groupBy(fun s -> nearestCluster s centroids)
    |> Seq.map(snd >> calculateCentroid)
    |> Seq.toList

  // Checks if two lists of same type is pairwise equal: if not => true else false
  let hasChanged list1 list2 =
    Seq.compareWith compare list1 list2 <> 0

  // Runs the input data and returns the optimized cluster centroids
  member this.Calculate seedCentroids samples = 
    let rec calculate clusterCentroids newCentroids =
        if hasChanged clusterCentroids newCentroids then
           calculateCentroids samples newCentroids
            |> calculate newCentroids
        else
           newCentroids

    calculateCentroids samples seedCentroids 
    |> calculate seedCentroids
```

Test:

```
open System
open FSLib
open Point2D
open Point3D

let createData count z = 
  let rand = Random(5)
  let min = -500
  let max = 500
  List.init count 
    (fun _ -> Array.init z (fun _ -> rand.Next(min, max) |> float))

// Test Case for Point2D:
let kmc1_2D (data: float [] list) (initailCentroids: float [] list) = 
  let seedCentroids: Point2D list = 
    initailCentroids
    |> List.mapi 
        (fun i c -> {X = c.[0];Y =  c.[1]})

  let samples: Point2D list  = 
    data 
    |> List.mapi
        (fun i d -> {X = d.[0]; Y =  d.[1]})

  let kmean = KMeanCluster(Point2D.compare, Point2D.squaredDistance, Point2D.calculateCentroid)  
  let result = kmean.Calculate seedCentroids samples

  result

// Test Case for Point3D:
let kmc1_3D (data: float [] list) (initailCentroids: float [] list) = 
  let seedCentroids: Point3D list = 
    initailCentroids
    |> List.mapi 
        (fun i c -> {X = c.[0];Y =  c.[1]; Z = c.[2]})

  let samples: Point3D list  = 
    data 
    |> List.mapi
        (fun i d -> {X = d.[0]; Y =  d.[1]; Z = d.[2]})

  let kmean = KMeanCluster(Point3D.compare, Point3D.squaredDistance, Point3D.calculateCentroid)  
  let result = kmean.Calculate seedCentroids samples

  result

let centroids = [ [| 0.; 0.; 0. |]; [| 20.; 30.; 40. |]; [| -40.; -50.; -60. |] ]
let data2 = createData 1000 3

kmc1_2D data2 centroids
|> Seq.map (string)
|> Seq.iter (printfn "%s")

printfn "\nEND 2D"

let data3 = createData 1000 3

kmc1_3D data3 centroids
|> Seq.map (string)
|> Seq.iter (printfn "%s")

printfn "\nEND 3D"
printfn "\nEND PROGRAM"

Console.ReadKey(true) 
|> ignore
```

Comment: @FoggyFiner: Thanks a lot for your thorough answer. Sorry for the late response, but maybe we live in different time zones? :-). I'll study it later in detail and then give some feed back. As for now, I can see you hit me with 3. about mutable variables. I really try to avoid them, but it's hard not to "fall back" to OO-thinking now and then. But I'm learning...

Comment: I wrongly made a response to you as an answer below.

Comment: Firstly you have some good points about the point types and the placement of point specific function. I would have done the same in my primary "world" (C#). I didn't here because I anticipated that in F# minimal date types is preferrable. (F# seems to be "bendable" towards nearly any paradigm and that's a little confusing for a beginner)

Comment: Secondly your list handling is excellent and shows a lot of details that I can learn from. Especially how to avoid mutable variables and how specific functions like Seq.fold works (I really like the List.init in createData). Much of the learning process in F# is apparently to understand sequence handling, and you give some very good examples.

Comment: Thirdly your code emphasizes the necessity to understand currying when working with functional programming. In KMeanCluster.Calculate you give a good example. Currying can be very confusing. I typically prefer iteration over recursion when possible - thats why the while loop and the mutable variables there. I'll have to adapt to a more recursive approach.

Comment: What I'm struggling a lot with is type inference. It seems you don't need explicit type definitions as much as I do. Maybe because my syntax is a little akward for the interpreter?

All in all thanks again for your effort and time. There is a lot of inspiration for me in your code. As a beginner, I'm not entitled to discuss any of your suggestions or changes - I simply have to see and learn.

Comment: Yeah, probably different time zones - I have UTC+3 now.
I don't know how there allowed off topic posts, I'm just a couple of days as joined this site. 
Whether it's a main SO I'd invite you to [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51909/f).
But it requires at least 20 reputation.
There is also a F# channel in Slack, it is more active than the chat. 
To join, you need to register on the website [foundation.fsharp.org](http://foundation.fsharp.org) and then you should get an invite.
F# community is very friendly, you can easily get answers to questions.

Comment: @HenrikHansen, I'm not in town right now, so can't edit my answer. I come back tomorrow and fix it ( I mean using `Index`)

Comment: okay, I done it :)

Comment: Thank you very much, that's elegant and clean. I really appreciate our answer.

Comment: Your answer of course :-)